# Django template text does not get translated with LocaleMiddleware

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n

Like in the subject, I have two strings to translate:

```
<div class="front-quote">
<p> {% blocktrans %} My, ludzie, mamy skłonność doświadczania samych siebie jako czegoś oddzielnego od otaczającego nas Wszechświata. Jest to łudzenie naszej świadomości, jak zamykanie sie w więzieniu. Nasze zadanie to wyzwolić sie z tego więzienia poprzez rozszerzenie naszego współczucia na wszystkie żyjące istoty i Naturę w całym jej pięknie. Staranie się aby to osiągnąć to nasza jedyna ścieżka do wyzwolenia i jedyna podstawa prawdziwego}wewnętrznego spokoju i poczucia bezpieczeństwa {% endblocktrans %}</p>
        <p class="signature">Albert Einstein</p>
    </div>
    <div class="front-1"> {% blocktrans %} Jeśli jesteś <span class="front-emphasis">idealistą</span>{% endblocktrans%} </div>
```

And for some reason the second one gets translated but first not...
I tried everything I could think of: changed the template tags from {% trans %} to {% blocktrans %}, put all text as one string in one line... It just does not work...
The only unusual thing I noticed is in the .po file, there is repeated and commented out block of code which does not get translated, it looks like that:

```
#: biostrefa/templates/pages/home.html:8
#, fuzzy
#| msgid ""
#| " My, ludzie, mamy skłonność doświadczania samych siebie jako czegoś "
#| "oddzielnego od otaczającego nas Wszechświata. Jest to łudzenie naszej "
#| "świadomości, jak zamykanie sie w więzieniu. Nasze zadanie to wyzwolić sie "
#| "z tego więzienia poprzez rozszerzenie naszego współczucia na wszystkie "
#| "żyjące istoty i Naturę w całym jej pięknie. Staranie się aby to osiągnąć "
#| "to nasza jedyna ścieżka do wyzwolenia i jedyna podstawa prawdziwego}"
#| "wewnętrznego spokoju i poczucia bezpieczeństwa"
msgid ""
" My, ludzie, mamy skłonność doświadczania samych siebie jako czegoś "
"oddzielnego od otaczającego nas Wszechświata. Jest to łudzenie naszej "
"świadomości, jak zamykanie sie w więzieniu. Nasze zadanie to wyzwolić sie z "
"tego więzienia poprzez rozszerzenie naszego współczucia na wszystkie żyjące "
"istoty i Naturę w całym jej pięknie. Staranie się aby to osiągnąć to nasza "
"jedyna ścieżka do wyzwolenia i jedyna podstawa prawdziwego}wewnętrznego "
"spokoju i poczucia bezpieczeństwa "
msgstr ""
"We human beings tend to experience  ourselves as something separate from the "
"whole we call The Universe. This is actually an optical dellusion of our "
"conscience, is like a prison for us. Our task is to free ourselves from this "
"prison by widening our circle of compassion to embrace all living creatures "
"and the whole nature in its beauty. This striving for such an achevement is "
"a path to our liberation and the only true fundation of our inner peace and "
"security."

#: biostrefa/templates/pages/home.html:11
msgid " Jeśli jesteś <span class=\"front-emphasis\">idealistą</span>"
msgstr "If you are <span class=\"front-emphasis\"> idealist </span>"
```

But I have no clue what does it mean... Tried to delete it but it is back next time

```
python manage.py makemessages -l en
```

is run

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

It is django 2.0.6 build with cookiecuter-django template.

UPDATE:

Translation works until I add the LocaleMiddleware (commented out here):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

Comment: Looks to me that this is a spacing issue: in your template, there is a lot of whitespare for `siebie     jako`, so this does not map entirely on the `msgid`.

Comment: That being said, typically translations are not that long. One aims to split it up in parts that each can be translated independently.

Comment: How can I write without spaces?? There are only single spaces between words..

Comment: that's not the problem, the problem is that the spacing in the *template* does not match with the spacing in the *translations*.

Comment: Really you shouldn't use translations like that. Use a short string as the key, and have translation files for both English and Polish.

Comment: It was a mistake from moving the text to stackoverflow post, corrected now. Text in template is one single line with single spaces between words.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Original text is in Polish in template and I have a translation file for English. Do I need another translation file for Polish?? How?

Answer (score 0):

The fuzzy mark on your first translation (followed by the previous original text), indicates that the original text has changed, so you have to delete the fuzzy line (and the previous text):

```
#: biostrefa/templates/pages/home.html:8
msgid ""
" My, ludzie, mamy skłonność doświadczania samych siebie jako czegoś "
"oddzielnego od otaczającego nas Wszechświata. Jest to łudzenie naszej "
"świadomości, jak zamykanie sie w więzieniu. Nasze zadanie to wyzwolić sie z "
"tego więzienia poprzez rozszerzenie naszego współczucia na wszystkie żyjące "
"istoty i Naturę w całym jej pięknie. Staranie się aby to osiągnąć to nasza "
"jedyna ścieżka do wyzwolenia i jedyna podstawa prawdziwego}wewnętrznego "
"spokoju i poczucia bezpieczeństwa "
msgstr ""
"We human beings tend to experience  ourselves as something separate from the "
"whole we call The Universe. This is actually an optical dellusion of our "
"conscience, is like a prison for us. Our task is to free ourselves from this "
"prison by widening our circle of compassion to embrace all living creatures "
"and the whole nature in its beauty. This striving for such an achevement is "
"a path to our liberation and the only true fundation of our inner peace and "
"security."

#: biostrefa/templates/pages/home.html:11
msgid " Jeśli jesteś <span class=\"front-emphasis\">idealistą</span>"
msgstr "If you are <span class=\"front-emphasis\"> idealist </span>"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Julio, I am pretty sure I tried it before and it did not work but now it does :)

Comment: Unfortunately it stops working when I add LocaleMidleware... any ideas?

Comment: `LocaleMiddleware` is used to let the user choose the language he prefer, as noted in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). If Django considers you are polish, you will get the polish text. One way to check that it is working, is using [internationalization in URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Also, make sure to configure properly `LOCALE_PATHS` to point to your translations directory.

Comment: the thing is the second, smaller block of text gets translated as it should, but the first, bigger does not... so it cannot be the LOCALE_PATHS problem, right? and both are getting translated until I add the LocaleMiddleware...